# JMH. Making the Microbenchmark's results public

Tags: java, microbenchmark, jmh

I have read that in order to avoid dead code elimination in microbenchmarks the most common solutions are:

1. Return the result of the calculation
2. Consume the result using a black hole.

My question is:

Could be possible to avoid dead code elimination by placing the calculation's results in a public variable?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Shipilev's answer I realized that returning the results or consuming them using blackholes must be done properly in order to avoid dead code elminination (DCE), as explained in the JMH examples.

**Therefore, I will rewrite my question to make it clearer:**

In cases when returning the result of the calculation or consuming it with blackwholes *is enough* to avoid DCE, is also enough to place results in a public variable?

I have run a variation of the example [JMHSample_08_DeadCode](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/d08717869985/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_08_DeadCode.java)  like this:

```
public double sink;

@Benchmark
public void measureRightPerhaps_2() {
    // What could possibly go wrong?
    sink = Math.log(x);
}
```

and from the results it seems so:

```
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
baseline               avgt   15   0,458 � 0,001  ns/op
measureRight           avgt   15  33,233 � 0,268  ns/op
measureRightPerhaps_2  avgt   15  30,177 � 0,603  ns/op
measureWrong           avgt   15   0,459 � 0,001  ns/op
measureWrong_2         avgt   15   0,917 � 0,001  ns/op
```

Comment: The framework cannot give a guarantee for that. But you can use perfasm to see at what you are measuring for your individual case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarks @RafaelWinterhalter. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple to answer: nope, that's not safe, unless you are controlling the environment, verifying that no ill effects are happenning, etc. The simplest scenario how it breaks is for optimizer to figure there are several consecutive stores to the field, and eliminate everything but the latest store. E.g. take a well-known [JMHSample_08_DeadCode](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/d08717869985/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_08_DeadCode.java), and add this test:

```
public double sink;

@Benchmark
public void measureWrong_2() {
    // What could possibly go wrong?
    sink = Math.log(x);

    // Imagine this happens somewhere downstream.
    // Or, you are sinking in the loop.
    // Or, measureWrong_2 had inlined and the very next Math.log will sink.
    sink = Math.PI;
}
```

...then run it, and weep:

```
Benchmark                             Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
JMHSample_08_DeadCode.baseline        avgt    5   0.251 ± 0.001  ns/op
JMHSample_08_DeadCode.measureRight    avgt    5  19.034 ± 0.033  ns/op
JMHSample_08_DeadCode.measureWrong    avgt    5   0.251 ± 0.001  ns/op
JMHSample_08_DeadCode.measureWrong_2  avgt    5   0.326 ± 0.001  ns/op
```

Morale: Unless you know what you are doing, don't break away from what JMH docs mention as the supported way to avoid DCE.

UPDATE: *Of course*, you can find a corner case when some other technique is working. But, even if something is working at the moment, you cannot be sure it would work with some other innocious change. That's the whole point of using Blackholes -- they are working always. E.g. more sophisticated case [JMHSample_09_Blackholes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/eaec8520f145/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_09_Blackholes.java), where you can "accidentally" make two back-to-back stores in `sink`:

```
@Benchmark
public void measureRight_2(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(Math.log(x1));
    bh.consume(Math.log(x2));
}

public double sink;

@Benchmark
public void measureWrong_2() {
    sink = Math.log(x1);
    sink = Math.log(x2);
}
```

...and:

```
JMHSample_09_Blackholes.measureRight_1  avgt    5  35.837 ± 0.043  ns/op
JMHSample_09_Blackholes.measureRight_2  avgt    5  38.378 ± 0.071  ns/op
JMHSample_09_Blackholes.measureWrong    avgt    5  19.012 ± 0.009  ns/op
JMHSample_09_Blackholes.measureWrong_2  avgt    5  16.659 ± 0.018  ns/op
```

Oops. Blackholes are working, and sinks are not: that's a counter-example for your updated question. Unless you verify *every* benchmark using that trick, and scrutinize the code that you are using the trick as intended, you cannot be sure the trick is working. My point is that you'd better spend time figuring out the issues specific to your benchmark (99% of all benchmark errors), rather than trying to cheat a few nanoseconds off the harness. Priorities!

Maintainer's perspective now. JMH development tracks what is being done in updated JVMs, as they evolve. Blackholes are getting fixed along the way. The code shapes for JMH benchmark stubs are getting corrected. But, they are verified on the valid benchmarks that are using the advertised guarantees. We have no reason to care about benchmarks that do something on their own. If, e.g. compilers would be able to inline `@Benchmark`, unroll the external loop that JMH is doing, then it will set up `sink` for the trouble discovered above. In other words, if you want future-proof-ness for your code, **use known and documented APIs**, not some tricks.

Comment: Thanks Shipilev.Is very nice when THE man from JMH answers your question. I'm not quite convinced by the answer: in the example 'measureWrong_2' given, returning the result of the calculation won't avoid DCE, neither consuming the result with Blackholes. The optimizer may still realize that there are unused stores. So the problem (in JMHSample_08_DeadCode) is not ***how*** the result is returned, which is ultimatelly the point of my question. I will edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Pardon? Blackhole is designed is such a way that optimizers are oblivious which store to keep, thus keeping both. This is not true for just a plain sinked store. See the update in my answer.

Comment: I meant consuming the last operation. I miss the possibility of consuming all operations with Blackholes. My bad. However, making memory trackings is an extremely costly operation so the 'trick' seems a valid option to returning the value in a final sink.  Besides, why the tone man? I don't want to 'cheat' with 'tricks'. I'm learning. Peace.

Comment: What does it mean, "making memory trackings"? By my definition, `sink` is a trick: "magic" solution, that does not always work. It is not reliable, as the examples above show, making it a bad option for using in real benchmarks. If you want to learn, I suggest you read the comments in Blackhole implementation before trying to construct your own, to understand the full scale of the problem: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/eaec8520f145/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/infra/Blackhole.java#l158

Comment: Is indisputable the maintainer’s point of view. Agreed 100%. I don’t want to ‘invent’ a new blackhole. I’m generating benchmarks automatically, extracting snippets and making benchmarks around them, as described in: https://github.com/DIVERSIFY-project/signal-loops/wiki/On-the-generation-of-microbenchmarks. As the the snippets are blackboxes for me, I don't know where to add a BH.  See my prob? I’m still expecting sinks to act as a wall against DCE, since I haven’t seen an example that convince me of the contrary  (if you do sink1 = Log(x1); sink2 = Log(x2) the measures become correct )

Comment: Your question reads, "In cases when returning the result of the calculation or consuming it with BH is enough to avoid DCE, is also enough to place results in a public variable?". The answer to that question is "NO", and it is backed up by a counter-example where BHs work, and sinks don't.

Comment: In other words, there is an argument that any subsequent write to sink can obliterate the computations that stored into the sink previously. Benchmarks above prove this is an actual problem. This may happen during the code transformations you did not anticipated previously. The only more or less "safe" way to do this is one-time sinks, that are storing one and only value by construction. A simplest (and bad performance-wise) case of such a sink is a globally reachable List<T> of sinked values. Memory-less constructions lead to BH-like impls, AFAIU.